# Awesomium Webcontrol not loading any web page within WPF Page frame control

Tags: wpf, web-controls, awesomium

I have added Awesomium webcontrol in my WPF Page (Frame Navigation)
But its not loading any webcontent, but if i add the webcontrol in WPF Window, its working fine.
Please suggest me how to load a Awesomium webcontrol within WPF Page control
Below is the code which i am using in my application

Thanks in advance.

```
<Page x:Class="Project15A.SocialMain"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"          
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Project15A" 
    xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:Project15A.Controls"
    xmlns:my2="http://schemas.awesomium.com/winfx"
    MinHeight="300" MinWidth="500" Title="Project15A"
    Loaded="Window1_Loaded">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <my2:WebControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,65,0,0" 
            Name="webControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Source="http://www.google.com" />
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Comment: I've not used awesomium myself but from what I understand is it produces a texture from a page that can be rendered in your application, I'm totally guessing here but is the partial trust of your xbap preventing the awesomium library doing it's thang?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this one out.  It is not a bug in Awesomium.  (Though I think it should be on a quick start page.)

Awesomium supports two view modes.  Offscreen and Windowed.

Offscreen is something that very manual.  All input goes through you.  (Why the default events don't still fire is kind of odd).  I think this is the mode you will end up using if you want to interact with your HTML.

But if you want a normal imbedded browser window then you need to turn on the Window view mode.

Here is an example:

```
<Window
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:awe="http://schemas.awesomium.com/winfx" 
       x:Class="WpfAndSpa.MainWindow">
   <Grid>
       <awe:WebControl x:Name="WebControl"
                       ViewType="Window"       <--------------+
                       Source="http://google.com"/>           |
   </Grid>                                                    |
</Window>                                                     |
                                                              |
This is the key part -----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Vaccano for your reply, I will make this change and test it.